# Intuition/proof that $E(X)= \int X(w) dP = \int x d\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the cumulative distribution function of X

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral

Looking for more intuition/help explaining the equivalence of the following two integrals.

I know that the push-forward measure, or the CDF, of a random variable $X$ on a prob. space $(\Omega, \cal B, P)$ makes perfect sense as a probability measure, I'm just looking for more insight and an intuitive proof.

Prove that 
\begin{equation*}
E(X)= \int X(w) dP = \int x d\alpha, 
\end{equation*}
where $\alpha$ is the cumulative distribution function of X

Answer (score 3):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$ be a probability space and let $\mathcal B$ denote the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R$.

Any random variable $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb R$ induces a probability $P_X$ on measurable space $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$.

This by: $$P_X(B)=P(\{X\in B\})$$ for $B\in\mathcal B$. This $P_X$ is the distribution of $X$ and is characterized by a CDF $F_X$ prescribed by $x\mapsto P_X(\langle-\infty,x])$.

This equality can also be written as: $$\int 1_B(x)dP_X(x)=\int 1_B\circ X(\omega)dP(\omega)$$

Using the linearity of integrals and monotone convergence theorem it can be shown that this equality still holds when characteristic function $1_B:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is replaced by a $P_X$-integrable function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$:$$\int f(x)dP_X(x)=\int f\circ X(\omega)dP(\omega)$$

If $\text{id}_\mathbb R$ is $P_X$-integrable, i.e. $\int|x|dP_X(x)<\infty$, then we can take $f=\text{id}_\mathbb R$ to come to:$$\int xdP_X(x)=\int X(\omega)dP(\omega)$$
Another notation for the LHS of this equation is $\int xdF_{X}\left(x\right)$.

Comment: I don't see why $\int 1_B(x) dP_X(x) = \int 1_B \circ X(\omega) dP(\omega).$ Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: In general $\mu(A)=\int1_Ad\mu$. Applying this on $\mu=P_X$ and $A=B$ we find: $P_X(B)=\int1_B(x)dP_X(x)$. Applying it on $\mu=P$ and $A=X^{-1}(B)$ we find at first hand $P(X^{-1}(B))=\int1_{X^{-1}(B)}(\omega)dP(\omega)$. Now observe that LHS is the same thing as $P(X\in B)$ and that on RHS we have $1_{X^{-1}(B)}=1_B\circ X$. This because $$1_{X^{-1}\left(B\right)}\left(\omega\right)=1\iff\omega\in X^{-1}\left(B\right)\iff X\left(\omega\right)\in B\iff1_{B}\left(X\left(\omega\right)\right)=1\iff1_{B}\circ X\left(\omega\right)=1$$for every $\omega$....

Comment: This together proves that statement $\int1_{B}\left(x\right)dP_{X}\left(x\right)=\int1_{B}\circ X\left(\omega\right)dP\left(\omega\right)$
is the same as the statement $P_{X}\left(B\right)=P\left(\left\{ X\in B\right\} \right)$
which is true by definition of $P_{X}$.